# Windows XP detecting printer as USB hub - how to start again without reinstalling XP?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, drivers, printer

- Fresh install of Windows XP SP3. No system restore.
- Didn't install USB printer drivers before connected it to PC.
- Mistakenly allowed XP to auto install some driver which turned out to be a USB hub(!).
- Now I can't get XP to see the printer as a printer.
- Have tried uninstalling the offending driver in Device Manager and rebooting but it keeps being detected as a USB hub.

How do I revert XP back to a pristine, unsullied USB state so it doesn't know about the USB hub and will (hopefully) install the printer as a printer?

Comment: I've tried reinstalling the printer driver software but this has made no difference and there's no uninstall option (even in Add/Remove Programs)

Comment: The printer is an Epson TM88III point of sale receipt printer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just download the latest driver for your printer from the website of the manufacturer and install this driver. It should detect and set up your printer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what printer it is, but my Canon (for example) has an installation disk that you must use rather than the auto-detect of XP to get the printer installed correctly.

You could try using that to see if it picks up the printer.